# CQ5 FTP XML file

Tags: xml, ftp, aem

How can I poll a directory every X amount of time for a XML file and then import it into the JCR into a certain format ? I believe CQ5 has removed this functionality. Also can Adobe make that available for us lonely soles who will need it and need to customize it into something useful ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a feature was actually ever in CQ5 or AEM. In general, what you will want to do is create an implementation of the `com.day.cq.polling.importer.Importer` interface and then configure the import process via the Feed Importer (http://localhost:4502/etc/importers/polling.html). (Note - although the name implies it is *only* for feeds, this is not the case.

You can see an example of a very simple custom importer here: https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/commons/wcm/impl/FileImporter.java

This just imports a file from the file system and saves it in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I had a similar requirement and used [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to connect via sFTP and save the file into the repository.  This service was called from a [scheduled job](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html) which would then process the xml as needed.

Here is the relevant but of code using jsch to actually retrieve the file via sftp and then save it to the repo.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

        log.info(
                "connecting to {}@{}:{}",
                new String[] {parameters.getUsername(), parameters.getHost(), String.valueOf(parameters.getPort()) });

        Session session = jsch.getSession(parameters.getUsername(), parameters.getHost(), parameters.getPort());
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(parameters.getPassword());
        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel(CHANNEL_SFTP);
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        log.debug("change directory to {}", parameters.getPath());
        sftpChannel.cd(parameters.getPath());

        log.debug("get file {}", parameters.getFilename());
        InputStream stream = sftpChannel.get(parameters.getFilename());

        saveStreamToRepository(stream, resourceResolver, path, parameters.getFilename());

        sftpChannel.exit();
        session.disconnect();

        log.info("disconnecting from sFTP after retrieving file {}.", parameters.getFilename());

        return path + "/" + parameters.getFilename();

private void saveStreamToRepository(InputStream stream, ResourceResolver resourceResolver, String path,
            String fileName) throws RepositoryException {
        javax.jcr.Session jcrSession = resourceResolver.adaptTo(javax.jcr.Session.class);
        Node pathNode = jcrSession.getNode(path);
        Node fileNode = pathNode.addNode(fileName, JcrConstants.NT_FILE);
        Node resNode = fileNode.addNode(JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT, JcrConstants.NT_RESOURCE);
        resNode.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_LASTMODIFIED, Calendar.getInstance());

        Binary binary = jcrSession.getValueFactory().createBinary(stream);
        resNode.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_DATA, binary);

        jcrSession.save();
    }
```